# Although the type of the variable is correctly number, function keeps returning it undefined

Tags: javascript, recursion, return, undefined

purpose of this code is recursively sum the digits of a number. like;
473 -> 4+7+3 = 14 -> 1+4 = 5 and stop here. All of the functions seem to be working correct except, in the last function there is an if check to check if the number is below 10. inside the functions it console out the number and its type correct as denoted with comments but the return statement keeps returning undefined. what am I missing?

```js
let digits = [];

function extractDigits(n) {
  const digit = n % 10;
  digits.push(digit);
  if (n >= 10) extractDigits((n - digit) / 10);
}

function digitalRoot(n) {
  extractDigits(n);
  const total = digits.reduce((acc, cur) => acc + cur, 0);
  digits = [];
  if (total < 10) {
    console.log(total); // this works without problem ---> 5
    console.log(typeof total); // this also works --- > number
    return total; // but returns undefined
  }
  digitalRoot(total);
}

console.log(digitalRoot(473));
```

Comment: [^^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77914382/although-the-type-of-the-variable-is-correctly-number-function-keeps-returning#comment137359376_77914382) When `total` is not `< 10`, your function calls itself (at the end), but doesn't *return* what that recursive call returns.

Comment: @TuranARICAN Your `return total` is only invoked if `digitalRoot()` is called with `n` being less than 10. In your `console.log(digitalRoot(473))`, `n` will be higher than 10, so the `return` isn't invoked. Instead it calls `digitalRoot(total)` which will invoke the function again, but this is a separate function call, unrelated to your initial `digitalRoot(473)`. At your `digitalRoot(total)` the function is invoked, but you don't do anything with the value that is returned there. You need to return it there to pass it back down the recursive call chain.

Comment: @Ivar, yes you are right, now it is clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The initial call to digitalRoot(n) does not have a return value, and it defaults to undefined.

To fix this issue, you should explicitly return the result of the recursive call:

```js
let digits = [];

function extractDigits(n) {
  const digit = n % 10;
  digits.push(digit);
  if (n >= 10) extractDigits((n - digit) / 10);
}

function digitalRoot(n) {
  extractDigits(n);
  const total = digits.reduce((acc, cur) => acc + cur, 0);
  digits = [];
  if (total < 10) {
    console.log(total); // this works without problem ---> 5
    console.log(typeof total); // this also works --- > number
    return total;
  }
  return digitalRoot(total);// return the result of the recursive call
}

console.log(digitalRoot(473));
```

Comment: it worked and clarified me